# iOS Xcode 4.2 using StoryBoard to present a ViewController

Tags: ios, storyboard

The new way of presenting a viewcontroller using the StoryBoard.

```
    UIStoryboard* secondStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController* secondViewController = [secondStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Connect"];

[self presentViewController: secondViewController animated:YES completion: NULL];
```

The old way of presenting the controller Connect is like this

```
  Connect *connect = [[[Connect alloc] initWithNibName:@"Connect" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 

[self presentViewController:connect animated:YES completion:NULL];
 NSString *userid;
 userid=@"123";

 [connect setID:userid];
```

I want to call the setID function of the connect controller in the Storyboard way, how can I do that? Seems like I don't get an instance of Connect controller directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should subclass the view controllers so that you can control what happens when users interact with it (unless your app can function on segues alone.)

In Xcode, File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class.  Make a class like `MyAwesomeViewController` that subclasses (in your case) `UINavigationController`.

I like to make a custom method called `NewVC` in my custom view controller classes.  It can do everything you list above, plus any custom setup:

```
+(MyAwesomeViewController *)NewVC {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"MyStoryboard" bundle: nil];
    return [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyAwesomeViewController"];
}
```

This way when you want to create a new one you can just call `[MyAwesomeViewController NewVC]` and it'll return a new view controller instance.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting it as UINavigationController? Just do what you were doing.

```
Connect* connect = [secondStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Connect"];
```

Comment: because if I do, then connect viewcontroller will have a back button which I wanted.